# Convert a list to list with type-constrained fixed length

Tags: haskell, types, data-kinds

Let I define a list with constrained length. I.e.

```
data List (n::Nat) a where
  Nil :: List 0 a
  Cons :: a -> List (n-1) a -> List n a
```

Then I want to initialize this list from common list (e.g. input string with any length). Can I do that? Is it possible to write function (or class) like this?

```
toConsList :: [a] -> List n a
```

Or is this suitable only for a structures with length which is known in compile time?

Comment: Why don't you try it? You seem to have written the code already. (implementation: `foldr Cons Nil`)

Comment: I tried but have no success. `foldr` has type `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`. But for instance `Cons` has type `Cons :: a -> b -> c` where `a ~ a`, `b ~ List (n-1) a`, `c ~ List n a`

Comment: You can't convert to that type since `n` is not known. At most, you can define an existential wrapper `data List2 a where List2 :: List n a -> List2 a` and define `toConsList :: [a] -> List2 a`

Comment: @chi: In case of existential wrapper I think I can't unwrap it and apply for instance function g :: List n a -> (a, List (n-1) a). Right? So, there is no sense for such a wrapper. It seems that I can implement some algorithm in type-checked manner but I can't start it with real data...

Comment: @DmitryOlshansky You can apply `g` only if you rewrap its result later, or you use it to produce a non-list result. The existential is not pointless on its own, but it might be pointless in some scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, because that would require dependent types. The **type** of the resulting `List` **depends on** the **value**. As your type error shows, you can't use `foldr Cons Nil` (which would be the obvious implementation) to create the list because the accumulator must stay the same type for the entire fold.

As @chi pointed out in the comments, you can use an existential wrapper to ignore the type parameter to allow this to work. You would end up with a value that was `List n a` for *some unknown* `n`, which gains you nothing over just using `[a]`.

There is [`Data.Vector.Fixed.fromList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-vector-0.9.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Fixed.html#v:fromList), but the documentation there tells us that it "Will throw error if list is shorter than resulting vector." This means that it is really just asking you to specify the type (length) of your vector (list) at compile time, and truncating or throwing an error at runtime if that expectation is not met.

You may be interested in Idris' [`Data.Vect.Vect`](https://www.idris-lang.org/docs/1.0/base_doc/docs/Data.Vect.html#Data.Vect.Vect).

Comment: There are [GHC.TypeLits.someNatVal](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0-latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.9.0.0/GHC-TypeLits.html#v:someNatVal) and it seems that we can do `case someNatVal (length xs) of Just (p :: Proxy n) -> my_func p xs  -- (or my_func xs :: List n a) `. But I have no success with this also.

Comment: Sorry, I meant
`Just (SomeNat (p :: Proxy n)) -> ...`

Comment: @DmitryOlshansky `SomeNat` is an existential wrapper around a `KnownNat`